# Selecting address value from pop up in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, selenium-chromedriver

Developer Tools view of the popup

[image: Developer Tools view of the popup]

I have to select 2nd value in the list of addresses on amazon.com, using Selenium web driver

Here is my Code-

```
package TechniquesToAutomate;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Dropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        driver.get("https://amazon.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email"));
        element.sendKeys("dummy@gmail.com");

        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password"));
        element.sendKeys("abcd123");

        driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();;

        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-global-location-slot")).click();

        driver.switchTo().activeElement(); 
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector ("//input[@name=2OPOJECBKZWO3TPDJUPIG12Q1WNJDTIR2A2R2RITDJNW1Q6PXTQ2FQA2OXNA3KWU:1:milprpoqnin")
                        ).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("glowDoneButton")).click();


    }

}
```

But I'm getting an exception-

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="a-autoid-2-announce"]/input"}

Any input if there is something else that I can try?

Comment: Don't post html and code as images. Post them as text.

Comment: Thank you!. I have given the code, however for the developer tools, I had to go with the image for a better explanation

Comment: Looks like the input element which you are searching for, does not have a fixed name. Try searching using class name 'a-button-input'.

Comment: @Ravi More than the image of the element and html, the text based HTML would have been more helpful to analyze the issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Basically after logging into amazon.com, I want to be able to select the second entry in the address pop-up that comes on clicking "Deliver to" button on top left corner. That functionality is common and the inspect code can be accessed by anyone.

I'm not able to do so using the code that I have given above.

Comment: @Ravi try with different locators.